# Is there a minimum number of arrays inside a multi dimentional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I try to create a multidimensional array, I accidentally forgot to add `,` in between each sub-array.

```
const multi = [["first", 1]["second", 2]["third", 3]["fourth", 4]];
```

And I found that with browser console it gives an error in some occasions, and it declares the array in some occasions. Below are what I tried with Firefox web browser console,

First, I try to put `,` after the first sub-array.

```
const multi2 = [["first", 1], ["second", 2]["third", 3]["fourth", 4]]; 

return ==> Uncaught TypeError: ["second", 2][3] is undefined
```

But if I add `,` after the second sub-array, it will declare the multidimensional array.

```
const multi3 = [["first", 1], ["second", 2], ["third", 3]["fourth", 4]];
```

And when I try `multi3` on console it will display the array and the value of the 3rd element is `undefined`. And the length of `mult3` is 3.
Can you please explain why this is happening?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: If you piss a comma it will create a array access, like the `a[2]` operator. There is so key `"third"` to this will be undefined. You can't use the `[]` operator on undefined

Comment: @NicoHaase I just want to understand why this is happening and why the array is created in the second scenario.

Comment: In your first snippet, `["second", 2]` is a property accessor, not an Array, just like you can do `obj["foobar"]`, except that here `,` is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which will evaluate each expressions and return the right most one, so in this case `2`. So `["first", 1]["second", 2]` is equal to `["first", 1][2]`, this is undefined. and doing `["third", 3]` tries to access the property `"3"` from this `undefined` value, which is illegal.

Comment: If you had only `0` has second operands that would have produced `[["f"]]`, because that's the first letter of the first letter of the string  `"first"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`["hello", "world"]` is an array. `[1]` [accesses a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) called `1`, therefore:

```js
console.log( ["hello", "world"][1] ); //result: "world"
```

You can keep chaining the accessors

```js
console.log( ["hello", "world"][1][2] ); //result: "r"
```

If any part before the end of the chain produces `undefined` you would get an error because you cannot get a property of it:

```js
console.log( ["hello", "world"][42][2] ); //error
```

---

As for `["hello", "world"][1, 2]` it uses [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and is equivalent to `["hello", "world"][2]`:

```js
console.log( (1, 2) ); //result: 2

console.log( ["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2] ); //result: "c"
```